# Download not working in react konva JS video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, konvajs, react-konva

```
class MyVideo extends React.Component {
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  video.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
  this.state = {
    video: video
  };
  video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
    videocrossorigin="anonymous"
    video.play();
    this.image.getLayer().batchDraw();
    this.requestUpdate();
  });
}
requestUpdate = () => {
  this.image.getLayer().batchDraw();
  requestAnimationFrame(this.requestUpdate);
}
render() {
    return (
        <Image
            ref={node => { this.image = node; }}
            x={10} y={10} width={200} height={200}
            image={this.state.video}
        />
    );
}
```

}

---

**As suggested by *lavrton*, I'm using the above code to render video in konva js. It works. But, Even though I have allowed cross-origin from video and even from the server, it says the following error when I try to download using stage.toDataUrl(). Not sure what's happening!**
Access to the video at 'url/sample2.mp4' from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to try to set `crossOrigin` before you set `src` attribute:

```js
video.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
video.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
```